# Trying to create a UIPickerView with 3 columns and different row lenghts

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I'm trying to create a UIPickerView with three columns and different row count for each column. The picker view comes up but only shows 3 items per column. What I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

```
_pickerData = @[ @[@"blanc", @"1/8", @"1/4", @"1/2", @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", @"8", @"9", @"10"],
                         @[@"blanc", @"1/8", @"1/4", @"1/2", @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", @"8", @"9", @"10"],
                         @[@"item 2", @"item 3", @"item 4", @"item 5", @"item 6", @"item 7", @"item 8", @"item 9", @"item 10"]];


// The number of columns of data
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 3;
}

// The number of rows of data
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return _pickerData.count;
}

// The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return _pickerData[component][row];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your picker is only showing 3 items per column because that's what's provided by the `- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component` method. Whatever number returned from this method is how many rows will appear in a given column (aka component). You are returing `_pickerData.count` here, and there are 3 items in your `_pickerData` array, so this makes sense. Note, the "count" of an array counts how many first level objects there are in the array - not how many objects are within each of those objects.

What I imagine you want to do is return `_pickerData[component].count` instead of `_pickerData.count`. This will grab a specific array within your picker data and return the number of items within that array, which seems like it's what you are looking for. You're already doing something similar in `pickerView:TitleForRow:forComponent` so I think you understand the concept already. Almost there.

To deal with your 'id' warning, you can cast the object to tell the compiler what kind of object it is dealing with:

```
NSArray *array = (NSArray*)_pickerData[component];
return array.count;
```

Comment: I tired to fix my code by changing to return _pickerData[component].count   but know I receive following warning: Property 'count' not found on object of type 'id'

Comment: I updated my answer to show you how to remove the warning. This can be considered safe since you know the _pickerData is comprised of arrays.

Comment: Thank you. that fixed it. even so I don't really understand why. Also, what do you mean with "this can be considered safe since you know the _pickerData is a comprised of arrays"?

Comment: To address why it fixed the issue: the compiler looks to see what kind of object it is working with and if the specific method / property you are trying to access on that object is defined in said object's .h file. Since arrays can store any kind of object, when you say '_pickerData[component]' the compiler can't really know what kind of object will be returned, so it just uses 'id', which, in objective-c, just really means any objective-c object. So, in order for the compiler to know that .count can be used on said object, you need to cast the object to be an array.

Comment: This allows the compiler to basically say, "oh, ok, this is an array. let me see if arrays have a property / method called 'count' If so, I won't throw a warning, and vice versa."

Comment: To address why this is safe: since you are in control of your _pickerData (you set it up), you know that it contains only arrays. Casting is the process of forcing the compiler to work with an object as a specific type / telling the compiler what kind of object it is working with when it might not know any better. You could also try to cast _pickerData[component] as some other type of object, but that could throw an error since the true type of that object is an array. Hence, why casting _pickerData[component] to be an array is safe here.

Comment: if I understand right, the compiler needs an additional array to keep track of how many objects are in each first level object in my original array "pickerData"? is my understanding correct?

Comment: also, I created a toolbar with a done button for my picker. I successfully implemented that several times with other pickers which only use one column. But know the app crashes when it gets to my do done button (IBAction): // Defining picker done button method
- (IBAction)unitDoneButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    self.textFieldIngredientUnit.text = _unitPickerData[selectedRowUnit];
}

Comment: Yes and no. It already has the array, it just doesn't explicitly know that yet, and that's why you use casting. Your picker data is an array that contains 3 arrays within it. Arrays, by their nature, can contain any kind of object (not just arrays, but also strings, numbers, etc). If you were to say [_pickerData objectAtIndex:0], the compiler would return an object, but not know what kind of object it is dealing with. Since you know that object is an array (since you created your picker data), you can cast it to be of type NSArray, allowing the compiler to then act on said object as an array.

Comment: For the done button issue, you should create a new question since that is a different issue from the original one. But to give you some help, you are trying to set the text property of the button to an array. _unitPickerData[selectedRowUnit] returns an array, not an NSString, hence the crash.

Comment: thank you. Let me try and fix it myself based on the hint you gave me. If I really can't figure it out I will create a new question.

Comment: Sounds good, feel free to message me if you create a new question. It's not very hard. Just want to play by the stack overflow rules :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent: where you are returning the count of objects in _pickerData.  That count, based on your data, will always be 3 - because the array contains 3 arrays.

What you want to do is give the count of items within the array for the index related to the component being looked at.  So what you really want is something like this:

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return ((NSArray*)_pickerData[component]).count;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tired to fix my code by changing to return _pickerData[component].count   but know I receive following warning: Property 'count' not found on object of type 'id'

Comment: Just updated it.  You have to typecast the array element so that the compiler knows there is an array there, so in turn it knows there is a count property associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

your code should be in:​​

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return _pickerData objectAtIndex:component.count;
}
```

Comment: you have take picker data with 3 array objects that's why it shows three item

Comment: When I change the code according to you recommendations I receive a warning stating :"Member reference base type 'NSInteger' (aka 'long' is not a structure or union"